# No WiFi on Fedora 30

Tags: fedora, gnome, deepin-desktop-environment

sorry to jump directly to the issue, but I am facing quite a frustrating issue on Fedora 30. I have been using fedora on both GNOME and Deepin desktop environment till yesterday. Till yesterday I was having an option for Wifi on both Deepin and GNOME, but because I got bored with Deepin, I removed it yesterday using `sudo dnf remove "Deepin Desktop"`.

Now, today when I booted up my laptop, I saw no option for WiFi which usually appears on the top right drop down menu.

[image]

I have faced a similar issue when I used to run Ubuntu 18.04, so I knew that I could run wifi using terminal. When I ran `ifconfig -a`, I got this;

```
    enp0s20u3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.42.172  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
        inet6 fe80::4de3:e5f5:3a6f:f2f6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 56:a9:71:4b:c4:ac  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 500  bytes 168101 (164.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 884  bytes 969702 (946.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 50:7b:9d:48:f7:e1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2827  bytes 260162 (254.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2827  bytes 260162 (254.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:3d:1d:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0-nic: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:3d:1d:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But no wireless card is detected in this. So I went to WiFi settings, where I found the message shown below.

[image]

I have totally wasted my 6 hours trying to fix it myself. I tried `sudo dnf install broadcom-wl` and then `sudo dnf update` and finally rebooted, but nothing worked.

It all happened after removing Deeping Desktop Environment yesterday. Even after removing it yesterday, the WiFi worked for as long as I didn't shut down the laptop. Today, as I booted it up, nothing, the WiFi was gone.

Please help me with this issue.

EDITS:

Some points worth mentioning.

1. I am on dual boot (Windows 10 and Fedora 30) and WiFi is perfectly working on Windows.
2. As of yesterday, after removing Deepin, I had 3 other DE -> a.) GNOME b.) GNOME Xorg c.) GNOME classic. Today, GNOME Classic is also missing.

Its like my system has got messed up!

Comment: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/tags/broadcom may also have an answer for you.

Comment: I removed Fedora and installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, WiFi is now working. Although it doesn't solve the issue with Fedora, but my problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

i resolved this problems by download new driver *.ucode (my wifi card is intel). put it to /lib/firmware and restart.